# Dynamic tag incorrect casing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to render different  components from react-bootstrap based on the a string in a showModal function in a button, but I am getting `Warning: <MyModal/> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.`

This snippet does not throw the same warning, but it creates an element, which is lowercased, based on the string in the function.

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>text</h1>
    )
  }
}

class MyButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => showModal("Modal")}>Show Modal</button>
    )
  }
}

const showModal = (modalName) => {
  const MyModal = modalName
  ReactDOM.render(<MyModal />, document.getElementById("root"));
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyButton />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are expiring is due to react trying to add an **HTML** tag name `<Modal>` instead of the React.Component Modal.
The react renderer is trying to render an unknown HTML tag.

---

## More explanation

I did a small refactor of the `showModal` function to simplify the issue.

```
const showModal = (modalName) => {
  const MyModal = modalName
  const reactElement = <MyModal />; // equals to React.createElement(MyModal)
  ReactDOM.render(reactElement, document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

The thing is that the `reactElement` is not equal to the `Modal`.
The main issue is that you are losing the React.component reference and unable to resole it by only a string.

---

## Prepose solutions

So... what can you do.

1. Not use string. Just pass the React.Component as a value. (Ya I know its the whole point of the question but React doesn't really work this way).

```
<button onClick={() => showModal(Modal)}>Show Modal</button>
```

2. Use `key value pairs`. If you still like to use strings to resolve the React.Component you will need to store them in a pairs.
   where the key is a string and the value is a React.Component

```
    const bootstrapComp = {
      modal: Modal,
      ...
    }

    ...

    const showModal = (modalName) => {
      const MyModal = bootstrapComp[modalName]
      ReactDOM.render(reactElement, document.getElementById("root"));
    }
```

Hope this help.